# Decoding HTML Entities when putting them into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am trying to write to a MySQL database properly, but it's giving me HTML Entities instead of the character I want.

My page header contains...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Here's the code I'm using...

```
$team_name = "Ranieri&#39;s Ghost";
$team_name_converted = html_entity_decode($team_name, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO mydbname (team_name) VALUES ('$team_name_converted') ");

echo $team_name_converted;
```

- Echoed to screen: `Ranieri's Ghost`
- Entry in MySQL Database: `Ranieri&#39;s Ghost`

I know this is susceptible to SQL injection but I'll sort that once fixed.

The SQL Table row is a VARCHAR (40) and I have tried collation "utf8_roman_ci", "latin1_swedish_ci", "utf8_swedish_ci", "utf8_general_ci" and a few others but it didn't seem to change much.

Any idea how I can get it to write `Ranieri's Ghost` into my MySQL database without the special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is failing because you are not escaping the apostrophe.  You can do this easily by using prepared statements (as you should be doing with mysqli anyway).  In the meantime, `$team_name_converted = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $team_name_converted)` will do.

EDIT: `ENT_COMPAT` converts double quotes but not single quotes.  Use `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: +1 This goes to show that "SQL injection prevention" is not an afterthought, it's a basic necessity.

Comment: Thanks - this works, but I also had to change `ENT_COMPAT` to `ENT_QUOTES` above. Silly me didn't realise ENT_COMPAT actually ignores single quotes.

Comment: @Cully oh right; for some reason I thought it was the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
$team_name = "Ranieri&#39;s Ghost";
$team_name_converted = html_entity_decode($team_name, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

$val = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $team_name_converted);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO mydbname (team_name) VALUES ('$team_name_converted') ");

echo $team_name_converted;
```